# Notification Not Fire On specificTime

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to send a local notification. My Code is Below mentioned.
Problem Is that notification not fire. i tried all possible answered on stackoverflow. please suggest.
I clear all Notification on did finish launching and also set a user permission for the notification

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.loadData()
    for obj in eventArray
    {
        if (obj["notification"] as? Bool)!
        {
            scheduleNotification(obj["time"] as! Date, obj["title"] as! String)
            print(obj["time"] as! Date)
        }
    }
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
func scheduleNotification(_ date: Date, _ title:String) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH"
    let myhour = formatter.string(from: date)
    let number = NumberFormatter()
    let mynumberhour = number.number(from: myhour)
    let intHour = mynumberhour?.intValue
    print(intHour!)

    formatter.dateFormat = "mm"
    let myminute = formatter.string(from: date)
    let mynumberMinute = number.number(from: myminute)
    let intMinute = mynumberMinute?.intValue
    print(intMinute!)

    formatter.dateFormat = "MM"
    let mymonth = formatter.string(from: date)
    let mynumberMonth = number.number(from: mymonth)
    let intMonth = mynumberMonth?.intValue
    print(intMonth!)

    formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
    let myday = formatter.string(from: date)
    let mynumberday = number.number(from: myday)
    let intday = mynumberday?.intValue
    print(intday!)
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    //let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: intMonth, day: intday, hour: intHour, minute: intMinute)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = " Today's Event"
    content.body = "Event Is Generated"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: title, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
        print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what value you are passing for 'identifier' parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Problem I solved. 
I called a "func scheduleNotification" in "func applicationDidEnterBackground" and notification fire properly.